# Cannot add DLL reference with AddFromFile

Tags: excel, vba, dll, com

I am trying to use a COM visible .NET DLL from Excel VBA. I have been successful when registering the DLL using regasm and then manually adding a reference to it via the Tools -> References menu item in the VBA Developer window.

However, I am now trying to register the DLL without using the regasm command so that the Excel file can be used on any computer without registering the DLL. So far this is what I've tried:

```
Dim JART_Instance As Object

Sub Initialize()
    Dim RefPath As String, X As Byte
    Const RefName = "JART xxx"
    RefPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\JART\JART.dll"

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
        For X = 1 To .Count
            If .Item(X).Description Like RefName Then
                .Remove .Item(X)
            End If
        Next
       .AddFromFile (RefPath)
    End With
End Sub

Sub PostInitialize()
    Set JART_Instance = New JART.MainJobControl
End Sub
```

I have added a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3". When I run the above code I get "Run-time error '48': Error in loading DLL". I have loaded this DLL a couple times using regasm. Do I need to do something like change the GUID's used in the project and retry. I've seen code examples where this is supposed to work.

If I reference the tlb file instead of the .dll I do not get the DLL loading error. Instead I get an error whenever I try to use the JART_Instance variable saying that the reference has not been set. Even though PostInitialize gets called directly after Initialize and there is no evidence that any of the code threw an error or failed to run. If I try to put a "Stop" command in the PostInitialize function it tells me that it "Cannot enter break-mode at this time".

Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: So an alternative is to run regasm every time the sheet is opened with a cmd script. What would the consequences be of doing that considering that this file will be opened many times on the same machine and possibly from a few different places.

Answer (score 1):

Excel-DNA has a helper function that does this for Com Addins written on that platform.

It appears to:

1. load the addin
2. register it with CoRegisterClassObject
3. add it's progid to the registry
4. add it to the registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins
5. call Application.ComAddins.Update in Excel
6. remove all the previous registry entries
7. Unregister the object with CoRevokeClassObject

It would appear that once Excel has loaded the addon, it doesn't unload when the registry entries are removed and CoRevokeClassObject is called. It stays loaded until Excel closes and releases it.

So, it's doable but not easy.

Comment: @ AndASM: Okay so what does that mean? The DLL I'm trying to load is being loaded on start-up. I have tried closing the Excel file without the DLL being referenced and reopening it and I get the same result. Do you know why I'm getting the DLL loading error? Are you saying it is because Excel thinks the DLL is already loaded?

Comment: @Ian Basically a com addin dll cannot be directly loaded. You have to write the code in VBA in your spreadsheet or somewhere else to temporarily register it, load it, then unregister it. It will stay loaded in Excel after you unregister it, until Excel closes.

Comment: I'm still pursuing different solutions. I tried using Excel-DNA to embed the DLL into VBA (if thats the correct jargon), but I ran into a snag. If I try to put this line before one of my static (Shared) functions: 

<ExcelFunction(Description = "Set path of DLL", Category = "Useful functions")> _

I get a compile error saying "Name 'Description' is not declared". I've got VS2005 so maybe that has something to do with it. BTW I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. The ExcelFunction attribute is to export a function through the XLL interface, which has different limitations and restrictions than the COM interface. If you just want to use Excel-DNA to shim a COM addin for you then access an instance of your object from VBA look at http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Integrating%20with%20VBA. If you want high performance user defined functions in cells, then look at the ExcelFunction attribute and rewriting your code.

Comment: As a side note, I'm not familiar with VB.net but according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/zzmx5SVF19I the problem is you are writing `Description = ""` and it should be `Description := ""`, note the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've resorted to doing a shell command to register the DLL with regasm. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strWinCmd As String
    Dim retVal As Double
    strWinCmd = "cmd.exe %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe /u /codebase /tlb .\JART\JART.dll"
    retVal = Shell(strWinCmd, vbHide)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strWinCmd As String
    Dim retVal As Double
    strWinCmd = "cmd.exe /c %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe /codebase /tlb """ & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\JART\JART.dll"""
    Call Shell(strWinCmd, vbNormalFocus)

    Call Button_Handlers.Sleep(1500)

    Call Button_Handlers.Initialize
End Sub
```

For reference the Button_Handlers.Sleep just calls the system sleep method and Button_Handlers.Initialize does this:

```
Sub Initialize()
    'This JART.MainJobControl is the main class in the JART DLL
    Set JART_Instance = New JART.MainJobControl
    'Use JART_Instance
End Sub
```

So basically I'm trying to register the DLL at start-up and un-register it on close. My problem is that when I open this file on a new PC I get an error in Button_Handlers.Initialize. It tells me that I'm trying to use an undefined class (JART.MainJobControl), as if the DLL wasn't referenced. If I try to reopen the file everything works fine???

The way I'm doing this is manually adding the reference to the DLL on a machine that already has it registered with regasm. I then save this excel file and transport it to a machine that hasn't had the DLL registered and try to open it and run it. I think that since the reference is already added to the excel file, alls the code has to do is register it with regasm. Does anyone know why this wouldn't work? Am I not sleeping long enough. I may post this as a separate question.